# Convert camera intrinsic and extrinsic matrix to modelview and projection matrix on openGL

Tags: opencv, opengl, camera, perspective

I'm trying to convert camera extrinsic matrix and intrinsic matrix to modelview and projection matrix on openGL for AR.

The camera intrinsic matrix is estimated by camera calibration, and I already calculated extrinsic matrix (I knew the correspondences between world coordinate(CAD model) and camera coordinate).

Only for checking whether I calculated camera extrinsic matrix properly, I augmented CAD model on the image using :

```
P = KE
(u, v, w) = P(X, Y, Z)
```

where P : projection matrix, K : intrinsic matrix, E : extrinsic matrix, 
(u/w, v/w) : image coordinate, (X, Y, Z) : world coordinate of CAD model.
The result is shown as follows, and result is good. I confirmed the intrinsic matrix and extrinsic matrix is correct.

[image]

However, I failed to change those to openGL.(I want to draw CAD model using OpenGL on the image). Using below code, the object is out of window (By changing the projection matrix of the openGL, I checked the code could draw object. But it draws object at wrong position).

```
extern Matrix3f IntrinsicMatrix;
double fx = IntrinsicMatrix(0, 0);
double fy = IntrinsicMatrix(1, 1);
double cx = IntrinsicMatrix(0, 2);
double cy = IntrinsicMatrix(1, 2);
double alpha = IntrinsicMatrix(0, 1);
extern Mat InputImage;
double w = InputImage.cols;
double h = InputImage.rows;
double Znear = 0.1;
double Zfar = 500000;
extern MatrixXf ExtrinsicMatrix;
Matrix4f Extrinsic4f, Temp;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        Extrinsic4f(i, j) = ExtrinsicMatrix(i, j);
Extrinsic4f(3, 0) = 0.0f;
Extrinsic4f(3, 1) = 0.0f;
Extrinsic4f(3, 2) = 0.0f;
Extrinsic4f(3, 3) = 1.0f;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        Temp(i, j) = 0.0f;
Temp(0, 0) = 1.0f;
Temp(1, 1) = -1.0f;
Temp(2, 2) = -1.0f;
Temp(3, 3) = 1.0f;
Extrinsic4f = Temp*Extrinsic4f;

Matrix4f glViewMatrix = Extrinsic4f.transpose();
GLfloat model[16] = {
    glViewMatrix(0, 0), glViewMatrix(0, 1), glViewMatrix(0, 2), glViewMatrix(0, 3),
    glViewMatrix(1, 0), glViewMatrix(1, 1), glViewMatrix(1, 2), glViewMatrix(1, 3),
    glViewMatrix(2, 0), glViewMatrix(2, 1), glViewMatrix(2, 2), glViewMatrix(2, 3),
    glViewMatrix(3, 0), glViewMatrix(3, 1), glViewMatrix(3, 2), glViewMatrix(3, 3),
};

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadMatrixf(model);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
GLfloat perspMatrix[16]={
    2*fx/w, 0.0 , (w-2*cx)/w, 0,
    0, -2*fy/h, (-h+2*cy)/h, 0,
    0, 0, (-Zfar-Znear)/(Zfar-Znear), -2*Zfar*Znear/(Zfar-Znear), 
    0, 0, -1, 0};
glLoadMatrixf(perspMatrix);

glColor3f(1.f, 1.f, 1.f);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);     glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0, 0.0);
glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0);     glVertex3f(1.0, -1.0, 0.0);
glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0);     glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);     glVertex3f(-1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glEnd();
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

double fov_y = 2 * atan(height / 2 / fy) * 180 / CV_PI;

gluPerspective(fov_y, (double)width / height, Znear, Zfar); // 39
glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

draw3Dobject();

glutSwapBuffers();
```

Is there anything that I change?